# Mapping cylinders of fibrations

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $p: E\to B$ is a fibration, is the map $q:M_p \to B$ from the mapping cylinder
of $p$ also a fibration?

I know that it is if $p$ is trivial, or locally trivial;  and I know (from Strøm's "The Homotopy Category is a Homotopy Category") that the topology of $M_p$ can be slightly modified to make $q$ a fibration.

I wonder

1. whether the modification is necessary:  does anyone know of a fibration $p$
   such that $q$ is not a fibration, and
2. whether the modification is necessary if we assume the spaces are compactly generated
   (Strøm works with all spaces).

EDIT:  There is a natural injective map from mapping cylinder $M_f$ of the map $f: X\to Y$ to the join $X * Y$;  the topology on $M_f$ is modified so that it coincides with the subspace topology.

Comment: If your fibration $p:E\to B$ had fibre $F$ then $q:M_p \to B$ has pointwise fibre $CF$, the cone on $F$. If $p$ is locally trivial then $q^{-1}(U)\cong U\times CF$. I don't see where the modification of the topology of $M_p$ comes in this case at least!

Comment: Yes, this was what I was trying to say:   $q$ is a fibration if $p$ is locally trivial, without any modification.

Comment: If $E$, $B$ are metrizable and $p$ is uniformly continuous, and you replace quotient topology by the topology of quotient uniformity *everywhere*, then your two mapping cylinders will be homeomorphic (and also metrizable). The preprint about this is not on the arxiv yet (delayed by other sections) but I can share it. In fact, the two mapping cylinders are *uniformly* homeomorphic. So is there a nice model category structure on *metrizable* uniform spaces and u.c. maps? Unfortunately, not all pushouts are metrizable, though all adjunction spaces are. I wonder if some trick can save pushouts.

Comment: @Sergey:   this sounds very interesting!  I can wait for your paper to make it to the arXiv -- no rush for me.

Comment: The preprint mentioned in my previous comment is at http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3249

Comment: @Jeff: a word of advice. The term "fibration" means different things to different people. It's clear that you meant Hurewicz fibration in the above. I doubt the result you are asking about is true in the Serr e fibration case.